# Error disposing of bean registration [io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQConsumerAdvice]

Tags: java, junit, rabbitmq, micronaut, testcontainers

Trying to do JUnit 5 with rabbit testcontainer in micronat but got an exception as `Error disposing of bean registration [io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQConsumerAdvice]: connection is already closed due to clean connection shutdown`

**Channel pool**

```
@Singleton
public class ChannelPoolListener  extends ChannelInitializer{
    @Override
    public void initialize(Channel channel) throws IOException {
        channel.exchangeDeclare(ConstantValues.FETE_BIRD_EXCHANGE, BuiltinExchangeType.DIRECT, true);

        channel.queueDeclare(ConstantValues.COUNT_SUB_CATEGORY, true, false, false, null);
        channel.queueBind(ConstantValues.COUNT_SUB_CATEGORY, ConstantValues.FETE_BIRD_EXCHANGE, ConstantValues.COUNT_SUB_CATEGORY);
    }
}
```

**Rabbit MQ listener**

```
@Queue(ConstantValues.COUNT_SUB_CATEGORY)
    public Maybe<Long> Count(String id) {
        SubCategorySearchCriteria criteria = new SubCategorySearchCriteria();
        criteria.setId(id);
        Bson query = QueryBuilder.QueryBuilder(criteria, Bson.class).get(0);
        return Single.fromPublisher(
                this.repository.getCollection(ConstantValues.PRODUCT_SUB_CATEGORY_COLLECTION_NAME, SubCategory.class)
                        .countDocuments(query)
        ).toMaybe();
    }
```

**Micronaut testing**

```
@MicronautTest
@Testcontainers
public class CategoryListenerTest {
    private final IProductProducer iProductProducer;

    public CategoryListenerTest(IProductProducer iProductProducer) {
        this.iProductProducer = iProductProducer;
    }

    @Container
    private static final RabbitMQContainer RABBIT_MQ_CONTAINER = new RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq")
            .withExposedPorts(5672, 15672);

    @BeforeEach
    @DisplayName("Container should be running")
    void containerShouldBeRunning() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(RABBIT_MQ_CONTAINER.isRunning());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should search based on the name")
    void shouldSearchBasedOnTheName() {
        iProductProducer.findFreeText("Value");
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
ERROR i.m.context.DefaultBeanContext - Error disposing of bean registration [io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQConsumerAdvice]: connection is already closed due to clean connection shutdown; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to clean connection shutdown; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:258)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:341)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicCancel(ChannelN.java:1491)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicCancel(AutorecoveringChannel.java:642)
    at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQConsumerAdvice.close(RabbitMQConsumerAdvice.java:312)
    at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.$RabbitMQConsumerAdviceDefinition.dispose(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.inject.DisposableBeanDefinition.dispose(DisposableBeanDefinition.java:41)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.stop(DefaultBeanContext.java:290)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.stop(DefaultApplicationContext.java:171)
    at io.micronaut.messaging.MessagingApplication.stop(MessagingApplication.java:97)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.stopEmbeddedApplication(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:380)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.afterClass(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:307)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.afterAll(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:90)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:434)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$15(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:434)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:434)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:216)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:149)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:149)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Please file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-rabbitmq